# Zend Framework 2 .htaccess mamp pro

Tags: zend-framework2

I want start to work with Zend Framework 2.0 . I use os x lion and mamp pro. So to start I used this ***http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html*** all good, I see zend project index page, but

> To test that your .htaccess file is working, navigate to http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/1234 and you should see this:
>
> If you see a standard Apache 404 error, then you need to fix .htaccess usage before continuing. If you’re are using IIS with the URL Rewrite Module, import the following:
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

So I do this, import this lines to .htaccess file in public folder, but nothing change, I have 404 error,

I try to create action named "edit" in indexController, for example, but if I go to 
http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/index/edit/ I have 404 error.

What I must do to make it work ?????????????????????

Answer (score 1):

Validate that your httpd.conf has the rewrite module enabled.  Usually in /etc/apache2, make sure you have the line `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` in the module section.

Answer (score 1):

If you have default MAMP installation you can go to phpinfo from MAMP start page by clicking phpinfo tab on top. In phpinfo page you can find if mod_rewrite have been loaded. Just click Cmd + f (on Mac) and type mod_rewrite. It should be in "Loaded Modules" section.

Now you should setup your VirtualHost. Open `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and add this to end of this file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /absolute/path/to/your/projects/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /absolute/path/to/your/projects/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now add this line

```
127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

to your `/private/etc/hosts` file.

Restart MAMP.

After going to http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/ you should see "Welcome to Zend Framework 2" start page. After going to http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/1234 you should see **404 ZF2 page** the content of this page should be something like that:

[image: zf2 405]

If you see something like that everything is perfectly normal. It means that your mod_rewrite is working and you have been redirected to **404 ZF2 page** insted of **default apache "Not Found" page** like that

[image: apache default 404 page]

Comment: It's all works, but if I create new controller or action in index controller of application module I have 404 error, page not found. For example, only http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888 works, if I try to http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/new or http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/index/new I see 404 error in my broswer

Comment: Did you create view to this action?

Comment: yes, and if I change default action in module.config.php to my new action ('edit' - for example) It's works for zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888 but show 404 error for zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/index/edi...I worked with zend fw 1.12 before and now I don't understand what's a problem

Comment: I assume that you have not added any routes. ZF2 is not handling requests like in zf1 (:controller/:action) by default. If you want to simulate this behaviour you have to add route like in SkeletonApplication https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php

Comment: I use skeleton application and create controllers in application module and have this module config, maybe I should to add something to config file when I create new controllers and actions

Comment: Sorry, problem with my inadvertence, If I create new controller or action I should go zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/application/index/index, but I try zf2-tutorial.localhost:8888/index/index...                                                    Sorry, thank you