# Zend Framework 2 Album Tutorial 404 error occurred The requested URL could not be matched by routing MAMP OSX

Tags: macos, zend-framework, zend-framework2, mamp

just posted this on IRC channel ZFTalk too,

Hope I can get some help on ZF2, ZF2 Album Tutorial, OSX using MAMP. Skeleton framework, homepage is working.

Issue : After completing section : 8.5 Listing albums, you fill up the module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml with some code, then they ask you to preview the page on http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album.

I get a 404, The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

I headed to Google for advice. Found a GIT repository with a 'fully working model' of the Tutorial, so i got this to compare my code with. If i set up this as another host I get the same 404 routing message.

After carefully studying the manual, it explicitly states in the start that you will not be able to view anything other than the start/home page if your httpd.conf / AllowOverride is not set to FileInfo.

Decided to scan the whole machine for files called httpd.conf, just for  in case the path to the one I changed is not used by MAMP when powering up the server.

So found 3, changed all of them (Although 3 we're found, I believe the correct route is /private/etc)  My problem still exists in the code i wrote from the tutorial, as well as the GIT code of the 'working model'.

Has anyone encountered issues with this? found this on stackoverflow [Zend Framework 2 .htaccess mamp pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827304/zend-framework-2-htaccess-mamp-pro) which has similarities to my problem but has not resolved it. Can anyone in here help me?

Other routes taken involve : Checking for spelling mistakes in the code, checking the application.config.php has a route set up. Please advise? :)

Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Album;

use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Firstly, the .htaccess file you are concerned with will be in the /public folder of your skeleton application install. Any others will be relevant to applications bundled with wamp.

That said, it appears your .htaccess file IS taking effect as the error message you are getting appears to be a Zend Framework error; it appears that while ZF is handling your rewrites correctly, it cannot match the URL you are visiting to anything in the routing config.

Can you paste your module.config.php and your Module.php somewhere so I can try and identify the problem please?

Comment: Hey @SpabbyPHP, Thank you for the response! I am editing my post to include the code you asked for, it will be up in a few min. Much Appreciated. From the time of posting this, I abandoned that tutorial and tried 2 new books. Not helping :D If this is a config issue it will haunt me regardless of the book i'm studying. But let me get you that code quick

Comment: @SpabbyPHP further googling and IRC'ing did reveal that my mod_rewrite is loading, so i suspect your theory will be right *hope* (this was checked by running php -i and studying the modules loading)

Comment: just to also be clear on the coding, other people had issues on the application.config.php file, the line to identify the Module was added in the array. (i.e, the modules array has an extra line that states 'Album')

Comment: This looks good, can you confirm that you are no adding the full-stop at the end of the link you pasted (I'm guessing it;s there for grammar only but worth checking).

Comment: Can you also paste the full 404 error you're getting please, different 404 text mean different things :) Also, try popping into IRC and pinging me (GeeH) - it's #zftalk on freenode for more real-time help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this error with help from this [thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/404-in-zf2-tutorial-td4661020.html).

I think, barring any other misconfiguration, the source of this error - for me at least - was where to register the Album module.

The **SKELETON Application** comes with an **Application MODULE**.  Those are two different things and they have have their own `config` folders:

```
config                      // SKELETON Application config
module/Application/config   // Application MODULE config
```

The module needs to be registered in the Skeleton Application config file provided with the skeleton, namely `config/application.config.php` and **NOT** by creating an `application.config.php` file in the Application Module config, e.g. `module/Application/config/application.config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve is by configuring the apache settings in (httpd.conf) change the 
"AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".
Such setting permit you to override the config value by .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

If you see a standard Apache 404 error, then you need to fix `.htaccess` usage before continuing. If you’re are using IIS with the URL Rewrite Module, import the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

You now have a working skeleton application and we can start adding the specifics for our application. Please let me know if it worked fine from you.

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he did not see a standard Apache 404 but rather saw a ZendFramework 404, indicating that the .htaccess has been configured properly.